# Changing Platform Target with VS2003

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, registry, visual-studio-2003

In VS 2005 and VS 2008 we have **target platform** option in project settings. I think I know what the meaning is, that is, I read [this article](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/). To quote from there:

> If the project is set to x86, this
>   means the project is intended to run
>   only as a 32-bit process.  A 64-bit
>   process will be unable to call into an
>   assembly set as X86.  Reasons to set
>   your project as x86 include
>   dependencies upon native DLLs that are
>   only available in 32-bit or making
>   native calls assuming 32-bit . 
>   Applications and assemblies marked for
>   x86 can still run on 64-bit Windows. 
>   However they run under WOW64.  Visual
>   Studio itself runs under this
>   emulation mode since it is a 32-bit
>   application.

This, I believe, is exactly what I need, so that my program automatically read configuration from WOW64 if run on a 64-bit platform.

The question is this: ***Is it possible to set target platform with VS2003? If yes, how?***

Thank you in advance

Comment: 32-bit processes get redirected to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  Have a look-see with Regedit.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, VS2003 targets .net 1.1 and this only supports 32 bit x86 targets.  Remember that the first 64 bit version of Windows was released after VS2003.

So, you can't set target platform on VS2003, it always targets x86.

Comment: Thanks. But here's a question then: It appears that when I read `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(                          @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones" )` I am hoping that the soft will go and read from WOW6432Node when run on a 64-bit platform. Can I do it somehow?

Comment: The registry redirector will handle that for you. In 99% of cases you just use the same key name for 32/64 bit processes and let the redirector take you to the right place.